# Is it safe to directly convert a struct 'point' to another struct using unsafe.Pointer?

Tags: go

Is it safe?

> (*TeamData)(unsafe.Pointer(&team.Id))

Example code:

```
func testTrans() []*TeamData {
    teams := createTeams()
    teamDatas := make([]*TeamData, 0, len(teams))
    for _, team := range teams {
        // is this safe?
        teamDatas = append(teamDatas, (*TeamData)(unsafe.Pointer(&team.Id)))
    }
    return teamDatas
}

// ??
teams := testTrans()
```

Will the members of the `teams := testTrans()` array be garbage collected?

There are many structs and many fields returned through grpc and their definitions are the same as the local definitions, so I want to use this more efficient way(`(*TeamData)(unsafe.Pointer(&team.Id))`), but I don't know if there will be any risks.

Full Example:
https://go.dev/play/p/q3gwp2mERvj

Comment: "but I don't know if there will be any risks", well, package unsafe is named unsafe because it's unsafe. Any use of package unsafe should be avoided unless profiling identified a hotspot that would benefit from using unsafe. You did not profile, you should not use package unsafe. (And you really should put relevant code in the question.)

Comment: If you're trying to save writing code, there's alternatives such as using reflection. If you want to use unsafe.Pointer, it's better to `var td TeamData; td = *(TeamData)(unsafe.Pointer(&team.Id)); teamDatas = append(teamDatas, &td)` to avoid worries about garbage collection (and if the structs are memory-compatible, this is something that's explicitly okayed by the reflect docs).

Comment: @PaulHankin In fact, I want to improve program performance and reduce memory allocation. Thank you very much. and ` this is something that's explicitly okayed by the reflect docs` this is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [unsafe.Pointer](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer) describes supported uses. In particular:

> (1) Conversion of a *T1 to Pointer to *T2.
>
> Provided that T2 is no larger than T1 and that the two share an
> equivalent memory layout, this conversion allows reinterpreting data
> of one type as data of another type.

Go's garbage collector recognises interior pointers an will not collect the original allocation until there are no remaining references to that block.
Hence the larger allocation (`GrpcRetTeam` in your example) will be pinned while references to `*TeamData` exists.

Another critical consideration is the [alignment of the struct fields](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees). Eg:

```golang
type Parent struct {
    A uint8
    B uint8
    // 6 bytes of padding to align C.
    C uint64
}

type Bad struct {
    B uint8
    // 7 bytes of padding to align C.
    C uint64
}
```

In this case it would be invalid to use unsafe to extract `Bad` from `Parent` since the memory layout is different.

In most cases it's typically better to avoid `unsafe.Pointer` tricks unless required to meet functionality or performance requirements. It's often possible to refactor code to minimise allocations instead.

If you must use `unsafe` to meet performance requirements --
I would recommend implementing a test using the [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package to ensure the memory alignment/layout is valid for the child struct.

Comment: Thansk for explain `(1) Conversion of a *T1 to Pointer to *T2.`, can you explain the meaning of `minimise allocations`? thanks.

Comment: There are various techniques you can use to minimise allocations. Eg, share a single larger object rather can copying a subset, embed a struct (not a struct pointer), reuse previously allocated objects, store them outside a loop, in a struct, or maybe a `sync.Pool`. It really depends on the code in question.

Comment: FYI, I've added a section on ensuring a valid alignment/memory layout.